# i can't be install db-mysql on node.js project

Tags: mysql, node.js

when install db-mysql package on node.js proeject . this error occured

```
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/db-mysql
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/db-mysql

> db-mysql@0.7.6 install D:\vhosts\node.m.com\node_modules\db-mysql
> node-waf configure build

'node-waf' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

> db-mysql@0.7.6 preuninstall D:\vhosts\node.m.com\node_modules\db-mysql
> rm -rf build/*

'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm WARN continuing anyway db-mysql@0.7.6 preuninstall: `rm -rf build/*`
npm WARN continuing anyway `cmd "/c" "rm -rf build/*"` failed with 1

npm ERR! db-mysql@0.7.6 install: `node-waf configure build`
npm ERR! `cmd "/c" "node-waf configure build"` failed with 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the db-mysql@0.7.6 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the db-mysql package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-waf configure build
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls db-mysql
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7600
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "db-mysql"
```

Comment: I don't think `node-waf` is available on Windows. It was used to build native extensions ([gyp](http://code.google.com/p/gyp/) is advised today). You might want to try felixge's [mysql module](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) instead -- I think it's more widely used anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are trying to install binary module from source under windows using npm which currently does not work well out of the box. node-waf is just a build tool, you also need at least compiler and node headers.

Possible solutions:

- try to install manually (read [this article](http://joseoncode.com/2012/04/10/writing-your-first-native-module-for-node-dot-js-on-windows/))
- use non binary, javascript only module such as [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) ( `npm install mysql` )

Answer (score 0):

Try this command: **`npm install mysql`** from your command prompt or terminal...
the most common way to install a package for node.js is through npm.

Comment: The asker is using `npm`. The command you're suggesting won't work.

Comment: mysql and db-mysql are two different modules. One is native and another one is not. It should not be given as a solution but rather mentioned as an alternative.